# how to access element inside iframe in java?

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I want to get an element's `id` attribute that is inside of an iframe through Java. How do I access an element inside of an iframe in Java?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/iframe")).findElement(By.id("output-img")).getAttribute("src");
```

This is the code i am using to get image src attribute which is inside the iframe. When I execute this code it throws an exception saying

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"output-img"}
Command duration or timeout: 5.06 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(id)); //iframe ID is String
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
String attribute = driver.findElement(By.id("output-img")).getAttribute("src");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**EDITED**

Comment: I added to wait iframe to load, first wait to load iframe, second swith to it, third get element id, fourth switch back. try only to switch to iframe, if works then issue is invalid element address that are you searching

Answer (score 0):

Like any other element through `WebDriver`, just use CSS selector or XPath.

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id=frame] body span")).getAttribute("id");
```

But this selector is depending on your actual elements in the frame, you didn't provide much info about this.

Comment: Thanks Peter for ur quicl reply. Can u plz look ito the below url and help me?
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/how-to-access-element-inside-iframe-in-java

Comment: See also @Andrians answer.